# why $\overline{ X-A}= \operatorname{int} X-A \cup \operatorname{Bd}(A)?$ How $\operatorname{Bd}(X-A)= \operatorname{Bd}(A)?$

Tags: general-topology

Problem taken from **Munkre topology** book . Chapter $3$  -problem $6$ - page no : $150$

Let $A ⊂ X.$ Show that if $C$ is a connected subspace of $X$ that intersects both $A$
and $X − A$, then $C$ intersects $\operatorname{Bd} A$

Here  i got the answer  below  but i have some confusion in the given below answer my confusion marked in red box

[image]

My doubt : why $\overline{ X-A}= \operatorname{int} X-A \cup \operatorname{Bd}(A)?$ How $\operatorname{Bd}(X-A)= \operatorname{Bd}(A)?$

**My thinking**: It should $\overline{ X-A}= \operatorname{int} (X-A) \cup \operatorname{Bd}(X-A)$.

$\operatorname{Bd}(X-A)\neq \operatorname{Bd}(A)$ . Take $A= [0,1]$ and $X=\mathbb{R}$. Then $\operatorname{Bd}(\mathbb{R}\setminus [0,1])=\mathbb{R}$

$\operatorname{Bd}(A)=\{0,1\}$

Comment: $\Bbb R\setminus[0,1]=(-\infty,0)\cup(1+\infty)$, so its boundary (under the usual topology) is $\{0,1\}$.[[BD means Boundary, isn't it?]]

Comment: yes @TitoEliatron its about boundary

Comment: Remember that $x\in Bd A$ $\iff$ for every open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ it holds that $U\cap A\ne\varnothing\ne U\cap(X\setminus A)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition given in the book is $\operatorname{Bd}E = \overline E \cap \overline{X \setminus E}$, so
$$\operatorname{Bd}(X \setminus A) = \overline{X \setminus A} \cap \overline{X \setminus (X \setminus A)} = \overline{X \setminus A} \cap \overline A = \overline A \cap \overline{X \setminus A} =\operatorname{Bd} A.$$

Answer (score 1):

As Tito points out, $x \in \text{Bd}(A)$ if and only if every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects both $A$ and $X - A$.

And similarly, $x \in \text{Bd}(X - A)$ if and only if every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ intersects both $X - A$ and $X - (X - A) = A$.

Thus $x \in \text{Bd}(A)$ if and only if $x \in \text{Bd}(X - A)$. That is, $$\text{Bd}(A) =\text{Bd}(X - A)$$